# Help! Newton-Raphson explodes!

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, bayesian-optimization

I am trying to find the posterior mode of a log likelihood in order to implement maximum a posteriori. The parameter I am trying to estimate is actually a vector. I can find the first and second derivative analytically.

Now when I come to implement the Newton-Raphson scheme, the Hessian is not positive definite, and the sampler blows up! I have tried to "fix" my Hessian, but it is still exploding.

Are there any suggestions on what to do in this circumstance? Are there any alternatives to Newton-Raphson? Of course, this is a large vector (of length Tx1, where T>1500) and it needs to be done very quickly as it is part of a large Bayesian scheme. As a side note, the variable is on the positive real domain.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your equations you are using

Comment: Use trust regions. Or modify the Hessian (e.g., by adding a diagonal matrix sufficient to make Hessian positive definite). Better yet, use existing high quality optimization software. Another possibility, use BFGS instead of Newton (Hessian).

Comment: I've tried to make it pos def by adding (min(diag(Hessian)) + 0.1) and it didn't work (the Hessian is diagonal). Are you aware of a better suggestion? BFGS didn't work because it took too long to the point of seemingly no return.

Comment: My suggestion is to not use your own optimization solver. Use an existing high quality solver which uses either trust regions or line search.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely give this a go. I've used fmincon in MATLAB and it was too slow. What is your best suggestion?

Comment: KNITRO might be faster and more robust than FMINCON. There are many algorithm options.  You can either supply exact Hesaian (or compute hessian-vector products) or use Quasi-Newton.  For Quasi-Newton, either BFGS or SR1. SR1 might perform better than BFGS if there are significant non-convexities. What kind of constraints, if any, does your problem have?

Comment: I will definitely try all of your suggestions. The only constraint is x > 0